# I cannot delete a file field from node

Tags: nodes, files

D7 content type with file field. On edit page, displays attachment(s) with Remove button, but cannot remove. Get blue "spinner" for a few seconds.

Also issue with upload of file field. Upload action get blue "spinner", then no indication of file uploaded. If you SAVE node, file is attached.

No errors in D7 error logs or in PHP logs.

Was wondering if this is jquery version related. Anyone else experience same problems?

[image]

Comment: Could be a JS error, any error in the browser's console?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your devtools?